# Как продублировать введенную информацию во все инпуты?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как ввести информацию в один инпут и продублировать ее во все остальные?

```html
<input id="copypast"><br>
<input id="copypast"><br>
<input id="copypast"><br>
<input id="copypast"><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.copypast').on('input', function(){
  $('.copypast').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="copypast"><br>
<input class="copypast"><br>
<input class="copypast"><br>
<input class="copypast"><br>
```